# Minkowski space and its compactified version: What's the difference?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, topology

Minkowski space has the metric $$\mathrm{d}s^2 = -\mathrm{d}t^2+\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2+\mathrm{d}z^2,$$
with all coordinates range from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, and it's a *solution to the Einstein equation* in vacuum. We can "compactify" one or several spatial coordinates to make another spacetime. For example, we can identify $x\sim x+2\pi L$ to make the space part a circle (or a torus if we compactify more spatial coordinates). It's also a *solution to the Einstein equation*, with different asymptotic condition.

Locally Minkowski space and the compactfied version are the same, and if we are not able to send or receive signals that can travel around the circle, we are then not able to differentiate them. Therefore my first question is **(1) how are they different theoretically?**
The only global probe I can think up is the action. But their Einstein-Hilbert actions $\int R$ are the same. Therefore, my second question is: **(2) Do we need to include a boundary term such as the Gibbons-Hawking term when evaluating action of these two spacetimes? And how to do that?**

Comment: Classically, there is no local theoretical difference. You have to remember that the action is just a method of deriving the equations of motion, and classical physics is completely defined by the equations of motion.